# AS3 'drawPath' simple shape not drawing correctly - why?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, graphics

I want to draw a simple triangle in ActionScript 3.

I use the 'drawPath' method of 'Graphics' class.

here is the code snippet:

```
stage.stage.quality = StageQuality.LOW;         // Change quality to low so no anti-aliasing occurs
var trianglePoints:Vector.<Number> = new Vector.<Number>();

trianglePoints.push(0);     trianglePoints.push(0);     // Coordinate (0,0)
trianglePoints.push(20);    trianglePoints.push(0);     // Coordinate (20,0)
trianglePoints.push(20);    trianglePoints.push(20);    // Coordinate (20,20)
trianglePoints.push(0);     trianglePoints.push(0);     // Coordinate (0,0) - tried with and without this coordinate return

var commands:Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>(4);
commands.push(1);   // Move to
commands.push(2);   // Line to
commands.push(2);   // Line to
commands.push(2);   // Line to

var drawSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();

drawSprite.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFF0000);          // Color Red
drawSprite.graphics.drawPath(commands, trianglePoints); // Draw the path
drawSprite.graphics.endFill();

var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(100, 100, true, 0x0000FF00);
bd.draw(drawSprite);

var pngBytes:ByteArray = PNGEnc.encode(bd);
var fileReference:FileReference = new FileReference();
fileReference.save(pngBytes,"bd_custom_draw.png");

stage.stage.quality = StageQuality.HIGH;
```

I don't know why - but instead of the triangle having points at :

- (0,0)
- (20,0)
- (20,20)

The triangle drawn has points at :

- (0,0)
- (19,0)
- (19,19)

Here is a [screenshot](http://s8.postimage.org/7npsvhvpv/alpha_Bitmap_Data_custom_draw.png) I took from Paint-Brush, with the pixels shown:

[image]

Why is the triangle not drawn in the right coordinates ??

.

.

**Upadte :**

I have tried to add this line just before the 'drawPath':

```
currentMask.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xFFFF0000);
```

and this is the [result](http://s8.postimage.org/x6hn1g183/alpha_Bitmap_Data_custom_draw_with_line.png) I get:

[image: result]

I just can't seem to get the result I need !

Comment: Try `currentMask.graphics.lineStyle(0.5, 0xFFFF0000,1,true);` to turn on pixel hinting. 0.5 pixels are to make the actual line thinner.

Comment: what does pixel hinting do ?

Comment: [Behold](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#lineStyle%28%29) It should position your path points so that your line will be aligned to pixels properly.

Comment: changing to 0.5 and adding hint still produced same result as the 2nd image

Comment: flash is vector based and bitmap - is pixel based so during rasterisation you will have some loss of information especialy on sharp corners.

Comment: what does that mean ? how can I draw a simple perfect triangle , like [THIS](http://s17.postimage.org/9mgtg9p8t/perfect_triangle.png) ??

Comment: It means that points and lines are snapped to a grid of pixels, e.g. you could increase by 1 pixel your vector shape it may help - but it is not a solution, I think better option is to use class for drawing on bitmaps like this: [ByteArray's Raster class](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=67)

Comment: isn't it much much slower (performance wise) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try currentMask.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xFFFF0000,1,true); - setting the lineStyle line thickness to 1

Comment: still getting the 2nd image in my post, instead of a perfect triangle like [THIS](http://s17.postimage.org/9mgtg9p8t/perfect_triangle.png)

Comment: That image has 21 pixels - The other images don't show up, so I can't compare.

Comment: @Gone3d right click on the words "image" or "result", choose "copy image location" then open a new tab/window and paste the URL, should do. (I use Firefox for this, IE might work too, other browsers will work for certain)

Comment: See the images now - sorry. So if you're worried about performance on drawing a bunch of boxes to make the triangle - just set the lineStyle thickness to 1 and draw it from 0 to 19.  The extra pixel on the lineStyle makes it 20.  It seems like a hack, but the results should be what you're looking for.

Comment: I'd also test it at different sizes and shapes to make sure it covers all options.  You might have to tweak things depending on what you're drawing.  Good luck.

Comment: It won't work. The triangle is just to prove a point that when you want to draw a triangle from (0,0)->(20,0)->(20,20) you can't without hacking it and adding one pixel. It becomes impossible if you are trying to draw a complex shape, like a star, where you HAVE to have the pixels drawn exactly where you want them to be...

Comment: Is it possible you could create the all the images you need in photoshop and import them to the Library?

Comment: no. I need to render them using AS3 because the shapes might change according to user inputs...

Comment: What about not using line thickness at all and going with one pixel larger.  How are the shapes created?